# TSQL query help to return missing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Need query help for the following
I have a sample data, as below on one of my table.

```
Create table #MovieShows(Id int, Movieid varchar(20), Showtime time)
insert into #MovieShows values (11,'m1','13:00')
insert into #MovieShows values (23,'m2','14:00')
insert into #MovieShows values (34,'m1','15:00')
insert into #MovieShows values (45,'m2','16:00')
insert into #MovieShows values (55,'m2','20:00')
insert into #MovieShows values (64,'m1','16:00')
insert into #MovieShows values (66,'m2','21:00')
insert into #MovieShows values (81,'m1','20:00')
go

select * from #MovieShows order by Movieid, id


     ==========================
     Need a query to show the missing rows along with table rows. 
     Desired output should be

     Id MovieID Showtime
     11 m1  13:00
     11 m1  14:00 --New row
     34 m1  15:00
     64 m1  16:00
     64 m1  17:00 --New row 
     64 m1  18:00 --New row 
     64 m1  19:00 --New row
     81 m1  20:00
     23 m2  14:00
     23 m2  15:00 --New row
     45 m2  16:00
     45 m2  17:00 --New row
     45 m2  18:00 --New row
     45 m2  19:00 --New row
     55 m2  20:00
     66 m2  21:00
```

The query needs to show the missing rows with respect to time sequence, along with the table rows. The missing rows needs to be interleaved among the table rows.

Comment: I don't get the `id` column.  How do you determine the `id` for a non-matching row?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two steps:  use `cross join` to generate all the rows and then `left join` to put in the values:

```
select m.moveid, s.showtime
from (select distinct movieid from movieshows) m cross join
     (select distinct showtime from movieshows) t left join
     movieshows ms
     on ms.movieid = m.movieid and ms.showtime = t.showtime;
```

The only think I don't understand is the `id`.  How do you determine the `id` for a non-matching row?

Hmmm, here is one way to get the `id`:

```
select ms.id, m.moveid, s.showtime
from (select distinct movieid from movieshows) m cross join
     (select distinct showtime from movieshows) t outer apply
     (select top 1 ms.*
      from movieshows ms
      where ms.movieid = m.movieid and ms.showtime <= t.showtime
      order by ms.showtime desc
     ) ms
```

Comment: You gained rep for the CJ experience; from me :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method using a Tally Table.

First, generate all possible `ShowTime`s,which should be `00:00` to `23:00`. Then get the `MIN(ShowTime)` and `MAX(Showtime)` of each `MovieId`. Now do a `JOIN` on both result to generate all possible combinations of `MovieId`s and `Showtime`s such that the time is between the `MIN` and `MAX` `Showtime`.

To get the `Id`, use `CROSS APPLY`

```
WITH CteHr(hr) AS(
    SELECT
        CAST(DATEADD(HOUR, hr, 0) AS TIME)
    FROM (VALUES
        (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7),
        (8), (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), 
        (15), (16), (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23)
    ) AS t(hr)
),
CteMinMax(MovieId, minHr, maxHr) AS(
    SELECT
        MovieId, MIN(Showtime), MAX(Showtime)
    FROM #MovieShows
    GROUP BY MovieId
)
SELECT
    t.Id,
    mm.MovieId,
    Showtime = h.hr
FROM CteMinMax mm
CROSS JOIN CteHr h
CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT TOP 1 Id
    FROM #MovieShows
    WHERE
        Movieid = mm.MovieId
        AND Showtime <= h.hr
    ORDER BY Showtime DESC
) t
WHERE h.hr BETWEEN mm.minHr  AND mm.maxHr
```

<kbd>[**ONLINE DEMO**](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/484622)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2012 or higher, you can use a recursive CTE combined with LEAD window function as per following example:

```
    DECLARE @MovieShows TABLE
    (
        Id INT, Movieid VARCHAR(20), Showtime TIME
        PRIMARY KEY (Movieid, Showtime)
    )

    INSERT INTO @MovieShows
    SELECT 11,'m1','13:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 34,'m1','15:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 64,'m1','16:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 81,'m1','21:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 23,'m2','14:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 45,'m2','16:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 55,'m2','20:00' UNION ALL
    SELECT 66,'m2','21:00'

    ;WITH CTE_Shows
    AS
    (
        SELECT   Id
                ,Movieid
                ,Showtime
                ,LEAD(Showtime, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY Movieid ORDER BY Showtime) AS NextShowTime
        FROM    @MovieShows MovesBase
        UNION   ALL     -- Fill in the gaps by performing a recursive union
        SELECT   Id
                ,Movieid
                ,DATEADD(HOUR, 1, Showtime) AS Showtime -- Add one hour to the current show time.
                ,Fill.NextShowTime
        FROM    CTE_Shows Fill
        WHERE   DATEADD(HOUR, 1, Fill.Showtime) < Fill.NextShowTime -- Only perform recursive union where the current show time + 1 hour is less than the next show time in the current dataset.
    ) 
    SELECT   Id
            ,Movieid
            ,Showtime
    FROM    CTE_Shows
    ORDER BY Movieid, Showtime
```

The main advantage of this method is that it eliminates the need for additional lookup tables.

Answer (score 0):

Possible approaches to this problem include

1. Temporary Tables
2. Self / Cross Joins
3. Ammending the Schema so that all possible showtimes are stored in a separate table and then using an outer join to populate the results.